# mysql_num_rows returning zero

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","samy");
mysql_select_db("project");
if($con)
{
    echo "Connected Successfully "; 
}
else
{
    echo "Error" . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_connect_error();
}
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
echo $name;
$sql1 = mysql_query("select cust_id from registered_user where name ='.$name.' ");
$r = mysql_num_rows($sql1);      
echo $r;
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
$cid = $row1['cust_id'];
echo $cid;
?>
```

Since num_rows is returning zero therefore $cid is also not printing.
Don't know what's the error;

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `dot(.)`.

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("select cust_id from registered_user where name ='$name'");
                                                                     ^     ^
```

Also suggest to add error reporting like this

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("select cust_id from registered_user where name ='$name'") 
        or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: That, or keep the dots but add quotes `name ='".$name."'`

Comment: This though `$r = mysql_num_rows($sql1);      
echo $r;` may throw an error when OP adds error reporting. Is not using `mysql_num_rows()` correctly. I think that will throw a "convert to string" error, if I do recall. If OP wants to check if there is a row, then would need to use something like `if(mysql_num_rows($sql1) > 0){...}`